# Need to check whether any extension is present before query string

Tags: c, string, url, query-string

I have written the code to check the `query string`

Logic::if `query string` is `"?"` should remove all the characters from the `query string` and print the vailid `URL`.

```
        char str[] = "http://john.org/test.mp4?iufjdlwle";
        char *pch;
        pch = strtok(str,"?");
        printf("%s\n",pch);
```

Output::

```
  bash-3.2$ ./querystring
  http://john.com/test.mp4
```

But i have to check one more case

1. Need to get the `URL` only if there is any extensions present before query string?
2. if No extensions are present before the query string,need to skip.

I have tried this way,
    continuation of the code

```
        char *final;
        final = pch+(strlen(pch)-3);
        printf("%s\n",final);

        if(strcasecmp(p,"mp4"))
                printf("falure case\n");
        else
                printf("Success case\n");
```

It will work for `.mp4` extension alone.
 Incase if i'm getting `*.mpeg` or `*.m3u8` or `*.flv` as an extensions,it will fail.

Can someone guide me how to solve this problem and make it working?

Comment: Why not using a `std::regex`?

Comment: c++11 supports the regular expression. Here are some simple examples: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match

Comment: Just test the other cases as well. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

A query string is what starts after a question mark `?`, fine.

You should try to define what an extension is. For me, it is what can happen after a dot (`.`) in the last component of the url, where the components are delimited with slashes (`/`)

So you should do:

- first remove the possible query string including the initial `?`
- then locate the last `/`
- then locate the last `.` that occurs after the last `/`

If you find one, it is the starting point of the extension.

So assuming `pch` contains the url without any query string, you can do:

```
char * ix = strrchr(pch, '/');
if (ix == NULL) {
    // an URL without / is rather weird, better report and abort
    ...
}
ix = strrchr(ix, '.');
if (ix == NULL) {
    // no extension here: ignore the url
    ...
}
else {
    // found an URL containing an extension: process it
    // ix+1 points to the extension
    ...
}
```